# Rvm: Cannot uninstall bundler 1.1.0

Tags: ruby, rvm, bundler

I have a rails 3.0.2 project I'd like to install, despite the fact that most of my new projects are 3.2+

I went to run bundle install and got the following message:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":   In Gemfile:
    rails (= 3.0.2) ruby depends on
      bundler (~> 1.0.0) ruby

  Current Bundler version:
    bundler (1.1.0)

This Gemfile requires a different version of Bundler.
Perhaps you need to update Bundler by running `gem install bundler`?
```

"Not a problem" I think to myself. "New gem set, uninstall bundler 1.1.0, install 1.0.0 and we're away".

But no.

RVM will not let me uninstall 1.1.0. I can install other versions, I can uninstall other versions, but I can't uninstall 1.1.0. If I type gem list bundler, it shows 1.1.0, but if I type gem uninstall bundler (with or without version tag) it says 'gem not installed'.

Any time I create a new gemset it's installed by default…and I can't uninstall.
Any idea what's going on here? RVM version 1.9.2, if it makes a difference

Answer (score 32, accepted):

it is because gems are also installed in global gemset, and you can uninstall it using:

```
rvm @global do gem uninstall bundler
```

but you can also use the other version of bundler using:

```
gem install bundler -v '~>1.0.0'
bundle _1.0.0_ install
```

replace `1.0.0` with the version that got installed (if other)