# gem cleanup unable to remove bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Should I just ignore this error, while performing a gem cleanup?

```
gem cleanup
Cleaning up installed gems...
Attempting to uninstall bundler-1.2.3
Unable to uninstall bundler-1.2.3:
    Gem::InstallError: gem "bundler" is not installed
Clean Up Complete
```

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9346708/gem-cleanup-shows-error-unable-to-uninstall-bundler-1-0-21-when-upgrade-to-bund

Answer (score 0):

As [mpapis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/497756/mpapis) suggested in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9810108/rvm-cannot-uninstall-bundler-1-1-0). Try...

`rvm @global do gem uninstall bundler`